# error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

When trying to create my Google maps I get the error:

error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to Activity

I have imported: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; but I don't think that is the problem. The class from where it get's it information uses Fragments, however my methods need an Activity. I am trying to figure out how to correctly convert them. I have tried to convert the original Fragment class to FragmentActivity but then I get a error in my navigation where on the getTag() method. So I am stuck as to what I should do. I am still in the process of learning Android Studio.

[the getTag() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsEuK.png)

My code where I get the conversion error :

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import com.example.flow.displayClasses.WebscrapingScreens.GoogleMapsFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.*;

import static android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;

public class LocationHandler  {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private LocationResultListener locationResultListener;

    private Fragment activity;

    //private Fragment activity;
   // private Activity activity;

    private int activityRequestCode;
    private int permissionRequestCode;

    private final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private final int GRANTED = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    public LocationHandler(GoogleMapsFragment fragment, LocationResultListener locationResultListener,
                           int activityRequestCode, int permissionRequestCode) {
        this.activity = fragment;
        this.locationResultListener = locationResultListener;
        this.activityRequestCode = activityRequestCode;
        this.permissionRequestCode = permissionRequestCode;
        initLocationVariables();
    }

    private void initLocationVariables() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest
                .create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(0)
                .setFastestInterval(0);
        initLocationCallBack();
    }

    private void initLocationCallBack() {
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                locationResultListener.getLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
            }
        };
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) &&
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    private boolean isPermissionGranted(Activity activity) {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, FINE_LOCATION) == GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, COARSE_LOCATION) == GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermission(Activity activity, int requestCode) {
        String[] permissions = {FINE_LOCATION, COARSE_LOCATION};
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode);
    }

    private void promptUserToEnableLocation(final int requestCode) {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        LocationServices
                .getSettingsClient(activity)
                .checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(locationSettingsResponse -> getLastKnownLocation())
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    int status = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                    switch (status) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            try {
                                ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(activity, requestCode);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException exception) {
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                });
    }
```

The error :

```
error: no suitable method found for getFusedLocationProviderClient(Fragment)
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
                                                      ^
    method LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Activity) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Fragment cannot be converted to Activity)
    method LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Context) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Fragment cannot be converted to Context)
```

My GoogleMapsFragment :

```
public class GoogleMapsFragment  extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationResultListener, PlaceSelectedListener {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_RQEUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final float ZOOM_LEVEL = 15.0f;
    private static final int REQUEST_LIMIT = 3;

    private final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyApsuynhkRf3A7p3fgKQp01EEF8l4tggXQ";
    private final String PLACES_REQUEST = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&key=" + API_KEY;

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private ClusterManager<MarkClusterItem> clusterManager;

    private LocationHandler locationHandler;

    private int requestCount;
    private String nextPageToken;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private List<GooglePlace> listPlaces = new ArrayList<>();

    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_mapsgoogle);
        progressBar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        locationHandler = new LocationHandler(this, this, ACTIVITY_RQEUEST_CODE, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_RQEUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                locationHandler.getUserLocation();
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext)
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("Please enable location")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", (dialog, which) -> {
                            locationHandler.getUserLocation();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            boolean isPermissionGranted = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                if (grantResults[i] != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    isPermissionGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPermissionGranted){
                locationHandler.getUserLocation();
            }else{
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0]) && shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[1])) {
                    locationHandler.getUserLocation();
                } else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext)
                            .setTitle("Error")
                            .setMessage("Please go to settings page to enable location permission")
                            .setPositiveButton("Go to Settings", (dialog, which) -> {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",getActivity().getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(myContext, googleMap);
        clusterManager.setRenderer(new MarkerClusterRenderer<>(myContext, googleMap, clusterManager));
        setClusterClickListener();
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);
        googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);
        locationHandler.getUserLocation();
    }

    private void setClusterClickListener(){
        clusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(cluster -> {
            Collection<MarkClusterItem> clusterItems = cluster.getItems();
            List<GooglePlace> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (MarkClusterItem markerClusterItem : clusterItems){
                for (GooglePlace googlePlace : listPlaces){
                    if (googlePlace.getLatLng().equals(markerClusterItem.getPosition())){
                        list.add(googlePlace);
                        break;//no two places have the exact same latLng
                    }
                }
            }
            new ListViewDialog(myContext, list, this).showDialog();
            return true;
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void getLocation(Location location) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, ZOOM_LEVEL));
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new PlaceRequest().execute(PLACES_REQUEST + "&radius=500&location=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void getPlace(GooglePlace googlePlace) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, PlaceDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("placeid", googlePlace.getPlaceId());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class PlaceRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                String line;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                if (jsonObject.has("next_page_token")) {
                    nextPageToken = jsonObject.getString("next_page_token");
                } else {
                    nextPageToken = "";
                }
                return jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new JSONArray();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            requestCount++;
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject location = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");

                    String placeId = jsonObject.getString("place_id");
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getDouble("lat"), location.getDouble("lng"));

                    GooglePlace googlePlace = new GooglePlace(name, placeId, latLng);
                    listPlaces.add(googlePlace);
                    MarkClusterItem markerClusterItem = new MarkClusterItem(latLng, name);
                    clusterManager.addItem(markerClusterItem);
                }
                clusterManager.cluster();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (requestCount < REQUEST_LIMIT && !nextPageToken.equals("")) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url = PLACES_REQUEST + "&pagetoken=" + nextPageToken;
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> new PlaceRequest().execute(url), 2000);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As depicted in the error logs the method getFusedLocationProviderClient takes as possible parameter either an Activity or Context and not a Fragment

Comment: Yes I know, but I am using Fragments so how should I change my code that the method  "getFusedLocationProviderClient()" accepts my fragment from my other class. Do I convert my GoogleMapsFragement and is yes, how?

Comment: Using your_Fragment.getActivity() [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid name and type dismatching like this

```
private Fragment activity;
```

It reduced code readability.

About the error: you trying to pass fragment instead of context.
To fix the error change

```
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
```

to this:

```
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity.getActivity());
```

Comment: Yes I know, I was going to change the naming.  Thanks for your solution! :)